# ReactJS fetch data from api json file

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to access the data from this api. I know how to access it the data when it's like the following format

```
{
  "confirmed": {
      "value": 6429453,
      "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/confirmed"
},
  "recovered": {
      "value": 2804649,
      "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/recovered"
},
  "deaths": {
      "value": 385873,
      "detail": "https://covid19.mathdro.id/api/deaths"
},
```

I would do it like the following

```
try {
    const {/* data: {confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate}} = await axios.get(url); */

      data: { confirmed, recovered, deaths, lastUpdate },
    } = await axios.get(changeableUrl); 

    const modifiedData = { 
        confirmed, 
        recovered, 
        deaths, 
        lastUpdate
     };

    return modifiedData;
    /* return response; */
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

but when i am trying to access the data where the stats is, it doesn't work, where it's **nest json objects,**

```
 [
    {
       "country": "US",
       "province": "Louisiana",
       "county": "Acadia",
       "updatedAt": "2020-06-03 02:33:13",
       **"stats": {
          "confirmed": 428,
          "deaths": 24,
          "recovered": 0
        },**
       "coordinates": {
          "latitude": "30.2950649",
          "longitude": "-92.41419698"
       }
   }
]
```

I try the following:

```
if (county) {   
        changeableUrl = `${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`;
        try{
            const {data:{updatedAt, stats:{confirmed, deaths, recovered}}} = await axios.get(changeableUrl);
            const modifiedData = {
                cases: confirmed,
                deaths,
                recovered,
                updated: updatedAt
            }
            console.log(modifiedData);
            return modifiedData;
        }catch(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to access the api data? Thank you in advance!

Edits:
CodeSandbox link here: https://codesandbox.io/s/pickers-l6mip?file=/src/component/statepicker.jsx

**UPDATE WORKING CODE:**

```
 if (county) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`);
      const modifiedData = {
        cases: data[0].stats.confirmed,
        recovered: data[0].stats.recovered,
        deaths: data[0].stats.deaths
      };
```

Comment: I've read your question several times and I'm really struggling to understand what you're asking.  Are you getting your expected data back?  Is this question about how to reformat the data using destructuring?  What does the raw response data from the api call look like?

Comment: that json looks to be incorectly formated if you are showing full content

Comment: @Xesenix  
here's a link to the image of how it's shown in the console in the webpage
https://ibb.co/kg8d4fN
thank u! Please let me know if there's anymore clarification needed!

Comment: data is an array of objects and not an object from which you try to destructure properties within stats

Comment: @SethLutske thank you, sorry for the confusion, i wasn't able to get the data back because idk how to access the data where it's "stats". i am able to access the full data with const {data} = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`); 
i am also able to get the country county updatedAt info with the following code        
        const modifiedData = data.map((fetchedCounty) => ({
            country: fetchedCounty.country,
            county: fetchedCounty.county
        }))
but i just can't get the confirmed recovered etc from "stats"
Thank you for answering!

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you, then how should i change it to make it work?

Comment: @yw323341 Do you really expect more than one object in the array. Why i am asking you this is because, you seem to hit the API with county as a parameter and I suppose you will only have one object in array at any given point

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thank you for replying, i am trying to get the "confirmed" value the "recovered" value and the "deaths" value from the api, i am able to return the value of country updatedAt and etc, but wasn't able to return the object values from stats's object

Comment: I understand why you are not able to get those values but before providing a solution I need you to answer my above question which will help in providing a correct solution

Comment: I am expecting more than one object, i believe i am expecting returning three objects
thank you

Comment: Thank you for providing a codesandbox, it clears a lot of things. However there is still one more thing I would like to ask, you fire fetchUSData when you change both county or state and set the data in a single state. Will you want to overwrite the state if both values are set? Also what is the final structure of data that you would like?

Comment: @Shubham Khatri it will only display one set of data each timr, so yes i will overwrite the state data if another county data is selected, it will only display one set of data at once. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: Added an answer let me know if you have a different expectation, the data returned from fetchUSData can be modified according to your need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must note that you are receiving an array from the API and hence you need to gets the stats value from the first object.

You should only need to access the first object within the returned data array because you are specifically querying 1 county or 1 state and hence the expected output should not contain more than one objects

Also when you are making a query, you must pass on the state or county variables as objects instead of direct values otherwise you won't be able to differentiate which API to query

The updated fetchUSData method will look like

```
export const fetchUSData = async ({ county, state } = {}) => {
  /* let changeableUrl = `${url}/countries/USA`; */
  if (county) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`);
      const modifiedData = {
        stats: data[0].stats
      };

      /* return stats.map((confirmed) => confirmed.value); */
      return modifiedData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  } else if (state) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`);

      const modifiedData = {
        stats: data[0].stats
        /* updated: updatedAt, */
      };
      return modifiedData;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Also note that you state query, you need to update yourAPI endpoint, it seems to point to county

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/pickers-8prbb?file=/src/api/index.js:65-789)

Comment: i am able to get it work with moving some code with your example to get the values of confirmed, deaths and recovered. Thanks!
  if (county) {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties/${county}`);
      const modifiedData = {
        cases: data[0].stats.confirmed,
        recovered: data[0].stats.recovered,
        deaths: data[0].stats.deaths
      };

Answer (score -1):

So after taking a look at [your codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/pickers-l6mip), your function `fetchCounty` should look like this (in `api/index.js`):

```js
export const fetchCounty = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`${url}/jhucsse/counties`);
    const modifiedData = data.map(fetchedCounty => ({
      county: fetchedCounty.county,
      province: fetchedCounty.province,
      stats: fetchedCounty.stats,
    }));

    return modifiedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Then you're passing the stats from each county as a result aswell.

Comment: thank you for replying, 
i am doing this in my api.js, i did use useEffect to my picker.jsx like in the following img url, https://ibb.co/dMdPWVr
how would i access the data that's structured like the following img ibb.co/kg8d4fN
Thank you and sorry for so many questions

Comment: no problem, dont know how was I downvoted though but ok. In any case you would access each by their property name like so `stats.confirmed`, its a property of the object `stats` inside of each fetchedCounty.

Comment: @Rafel Rocha it's able to return it, but the value became undefined

Comment: can you create a codesandbox with your code? Might be able to figure out whats happening better.

Comment: yes, https://codesandbox.io/s/pickers-l6mip?file=/src/component/statepicker.jsx
thank you!

Comment: so you're not passing the property `stats` from the result of your api call :)

Comment: `stats: county.stats` and then you'll set it in the useEffect :)

Comment: does this belong to fetchusdata in the api/index.js for the county function?

Comment: exactly, because its coming from the API.

Comment: oh, for that fetchCounty function it's only for showing the list of county names in the picker, so its not this function but thank you for replying

Comment: you can have another function that getsStats for each county. And you can get it immediately from the state without having to call the api again since you already have the data right?

Comment: Thank you, i got the answer from another answer though! But thank you very much for helping me out!